# Run NPM script before all other scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'm looking for a way to run a script any time I use `npm run <script-name>`.

My current use-case is that I want to run a script that ensures the dev environment is setup correctly before running any of my other scripts.

So, what I need is something like this:

```json
{
    "run-before-all-scripts": "./setup_environment.sh",
    "scripts": {
        "script_one": "do something",
        "script_two": "do somethingelse"
    }
    ...
}
```

The best I have come up with is this:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "setup_environment": "./setup_environment.sh",
        "script_one": "npm run setup_environment && do something",
        "script_two": "npm run setup_environment && do somethingelse"
    }
    ...
}
```

The only better solution I've come up with is to just create a wrapper shell script around the `npm` command, so I can call `fancy_npm_run <command>`. That just seems kind of messy though.

Is there a better way to handle this?

I've read [npm script hook on multiple scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60851108/npm-script-hook-on-multiple-scripts) but it is not about running before all scripts and also is not answered.

Comment: There's no `preeverything` hook for run-script, no. Why not just set up the environment as e.g. a postinstall step?

Comment: @jonrsharpe As an example, my current situation is that I have projects depending on different versions of NodeJS, and I want to tell NVM to switch to the correct version. It's common that I switch between projects without running `install`, so I don't think `postinstall` will work.

Comment: It's useful to include that kind of context in the question to avoid [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you use the [`engines`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#engines) field it'll complain when you try to run the wrong versions. You can also use tools like https://direnv.net/ to switch to the appropriate version as you change directory based on a `.nvmrc`, without having to run any command.

Comment: I feel like there is a solution here via using a custom script-shell command via .npmrc. That shell could run whatever you want to run, before then running the commands it has been asked to run. Not tested though, so an exercise for the reader to make this work...